# Flutter Angela Yu example

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to print first element in the list "first ques"
but I'm getting different sort of errors tried using final also, then all sort of errors.

```
class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  List<Widget> scoreKeeper = [];

  List<String> questions = ["First ques", "seacond ques", "third ques"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text( 
                "example text"
                questions[0], //why its not displaying "first ques"
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: check properly your code of Text( 
                "example text"
                questions[0]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
    List<Widget> scoreKeeper = [];

    List<String> questions = ["First ques", "seacond ques", "third ques"];
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Text( 
                  questions[0], //why its not displaying "first ques"
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

the reason you are getting error is that the Text widget takes only one string and you are passing two string to it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should remove `const` from the `Expanded` widget because you're using a variable inside on `Text` which is `questions[0]`.

And I want to mention that its better to use `questions.first` for readability proposes and check if the list is empty before it to prevent possible errors.

So Here's the final result:

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        flex: 5,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              questions.first,
              //why its not displaying "first ques"
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```